# change regex to match some words instead of all words containing PRP

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex matches all characters between whitespace if the word contains `PRP`.

How can I get it to match all words, or characters in-between whitepsace, if they contain `PRP`, but not if they contain `me` in any case.

So match all words containing PRP, but not containing ME or me.

Here is the regex to match words containing PRP: `\S*PRP\S*`

Comment: can you provide some inputs along with expected outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead for this:

```
(?:^|\s)((?!\S*?(?:ME|me))\S*?PRP\S*)
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hJ2wM6)

**PS:** Use group `#1` for your matched word.

**Code:**

```
var re = /(?:^|\s)((?!\S*?(?:ME|me))\S*?PRP\S*)/;    
var s = 'word abcPRP def';

var m = s.match(re);    
if (m) console.log(m[1]); //=> abcPRP
```

Comment: thank you, but it is not working in this regex tester site: http://www.regexr.com/ I think there is an unmatched paratheses

Comment: Check latest regex and linked demo.

Comment: it is actually matching me(PRP). I want it to match all things containing PRP except me(PRP) or ME(PRP)

Comment: it is still matching the (PRP) even if the word contains me. I want it to match nothing if the word contains me. Here is a link: http://regex101.com/r/hR3mS2

Comment: thank you very much! one last thing, it is matching the space before the match as well. I want it to only match things character in-between the whitespace excluding all whitespace surrounding the match

Comment: ok see updated answer now and use group `#1` for your matched word.

Comment: what do you mean by use group #1? I plan on matching and replacing what ever is matched. That is why I need it to be only the word and no whitespace.

Comment: Matched group #1 is what is captured in `group #1` in brackets. You will see captured group in bottom-right of the deme link I provided.

Comment: yes, but how do I access that and only that? Sorry i'm a novice to regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using complicated regular expressions which would be confusing for almost anyone who's reading it, why don't you break up your code into two sections, separating the words into an array and filtering out the results with stuff you don't want?

```
function prpnotme(w) {
  var r = w.match(/\S+/g);
  if(r == null)
    return [];
  var i=0;
  while(i<r.length) {
    if(!r[i].contains('PRP') || r[i].toLowerCase().contains('me'))
      r.splice(i,1);
    else
      i++;
  }
  return r;
}
console.log(prpnotme('whattttttt ok')); // []
console.log(prpnotme('MELOLPRP PRPRP PRPthemeok PRPmhm')); // ['PRPRP', 'PRPmhm']
```

For a very good reason why this is important, imagine if you ever wanted to add more logic. You're much more likely to make a mistake when modifying complicated regex to make it even more complicated, and this way it's done with simple logic that make perfect sense when reading each predicate, no matter how much you add on.